# How to init a STM32 timer in input capture mode?

Tags: input, timer, embedded, stm32

I have an STM32F4 MCU and I'm writing a timer driver. I want to add the input capture functionality to the timer, but can't accomplish it, so I have a couple of questions:

1. How should I configure the GPIO pin I intend to use for signal input?
   At the moment I use this:

   ```
   #define GPIO_PPM_PIN (GPIO_ALT|GPIO_AF1|GPIO_PULLUP|GPIO_PORTB|GPIO_PIN4)
   ```
2. How do I configure the timer? I follow everything the reference manual says, but that does not help

Here is an example of my timer registers configuration(for channel 1):

```
        config->regs->CR1 = 0;
        config->regs->CR2 = 0;
        config->regs->SMCR = 0;
        config->regs->DIER = GTIM_DIER_CC1IE; //enable interrupt request

        config->regs->CCER = 0; // unlock CCMR registers
        config->regs->CCMR1 = GTIM_CCMR_CCS_CCIN1 << GTIM_CCMR1_CC1S_SHIFT;
        config->regs->CCMR2 = 0; //
        config->regs->CCER = (GTIM_CCER_CC1E | GTIM_CCER_CC1P | GTIM_CCER_CC1NP);
        config->regs->DCR = 0;

        config->regs->PSC = (config->clock / 1000000) - 1;
        config->regs->ARR = 0xFFFF;
        config->regs->CCR1 = 1000;
        config->regs->EGR = GTIM_EGR_UG;
        config->regs->CR1 = GTIM_CR1_CEN;

        up_enable_irq(config->interrupt);

        stm32_configgpio(GPIO_INPUT_PIN);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of using the Standard Peripheral Library for peripheral initialization? Much easier to visualize what the code is doing, compared to setting a bunch of bits as you're doing there. Also, I have no idea about the syntax in your first #define up there so I have no idea if it's right or wrong. If you're using an unusual library or if you rolled your own code, you should mention it.

Comment: @swineone Yes indeed, I'm not using the Std Periph Library, because it's bulky and I'm writing my own driver. If you worry about the set up I have for the driver, then don't: the registers change just the way they are expected after running this code, it's just that the desired effect of input capture is not achieved. My question is about what settings should be in the registers, not how to change them.

Comment: @Egor Did you resolve this?

Comment: @GisMofx I did not, sorry. I changed my field of work shortly after this problem, so I did not have time to get back to it.